# How to override method from the parent in multiple classes in the same way without creating class between parent and the child?

Tags: java

It's hard to properly ask, so I will create an example:

```
class Animal {

    public void doSomething() {
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {

}

class Cat extends Animal {

}

class Sheltie extends Dog {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
        System.out.println("Exactly the same");
    }
}

class Abbysian extends Cat {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
        System.out.println("Exactly the same");
    }
}
```

Is there a way in this case that I can override the `doSomething()` method in both `Sheltie` and `Abbysian` without duplicating a code and even typing `@Override public void doSomething()`. On top of that, I'd actually like to call `super.doSomething()` as well. I cannot change inheritance at all.

If those classes extended directly `Animal` I would create a class "between" them. I was thinking of using `interface` with `default` method but that didn't help as well.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the real source code you have or the source code which is more related to your actual code. It is unclear what other restrictions you have in your code. Also explain which part of the inheritance you can't change. Also add your attempts you have tried to your question and explain the problems you had with them.

Comment: Why not just wrapping the code in some static method ``public static <T extends Animal> void doSomething(T objectToHandle)`` ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you broke out into Cats and Dogs you discovered the limitations of class hierarchy - eventually you'll hit a point of no return.

Thankfully there is a thing called an Entity Component System (ECS) that is commonly used when you want to mish-mash functionality amongst many different entities.

A cat can wag its tail. A dog can wag its tail... but not all animals have tails!
So you register a component called Tail to the tailed animal entities.

I found this on the StackExchange code review group.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163215/entity-component-system-ecs

Answer (score 0):

`Decorator` pattern can do this trick but it would be applied to specific instances of `Sheltie` / `Abyssinian` not to these classes:

```java
class AnimalDecorator extends Animal {
    protected Animal animal;

    public AnimalDecorator(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        animal.doSomething(); // instead of call to super.doSomething
        System.out.println("Exactly the same");
    }
}
```

```java
class Sheltie extends Dog { // doSomething not overridden
}

class Abyssinian extends Cat { // doSomething not overridden
}

// decorated instances
Animal sheltie = new AnimalDecorator(new Sheltie());
Animal abyssinian = new AnimalDecorator(new Abyssinian());
sheltie.doSomething();
abyssinian.doSomething();
```